# Sequelize destroy command

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, instance, destroy

I'm trying delete one record, via destroy method of an instance.

```
const memCustomers = await Customers.findAll({ limit: 10 })

for (const customer of memCustomers ) {
    //do things
    await customer.destroy()
}
```

But when i use this command it delete all records in table customers, and when i add "where" argument for destroy method, nothing change...

I set logging equal true... and it show a "delete from table" without "where".

Comment: According to the docs, you need to add `where` to the `findAll` https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#applying-where-clauses. This should filter the results in the database.

Comment: Alternatively, you can do both steps in one go: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/paranoid/#deleting

Comment: @marcobiedermann i added limit equal 10 for test purpose only... my original solution needs all records by this i don't have "where" condition when i select the records.

Comment: @marcobiedermann if i use destroy method of sequelize Model passing where argument it works... but i don't know what happens when i use via instance it was supposed to work too right?

Comment: When performing an action on the instance, you can not further call the `where` statement. As pointed out in example 1. (see below) you would have to do the filtering in the app, no in the DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Filter your customers on the app side

```js
const customers = await Customers.findAll({ where: …, limit: … })

Promise.all(customers.filter( … ).map(customer => customer.destroy()))
```

2. Call your database again

```js
const customers = await Customers.findAll({ where: …, limit: … })

await Customers.destroy({ where: … })
```

This highly depends on the number of entries but I would always recommend doing the filtering on the database level

Comment: Your first solution, doesn't work for me... let's try to understand when I set "where" to "findAll" does this change anything in the instance?

I couldn't understand what the where argument of findAll interferes with the destroy of the returned instance?

The second solution i said it works, but destroy is called on Customers(model) not on instance. :) i really appreciate your help, thanks.